NameError - uninitialized constant Nylas::API:
I'm encountering a NameError related to the Nylas::API constant not being initialized in my Rails 7.1.3.2 application. This error occurs when I try to set up the Nylas client in my EmailConnectionsController.
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Allocations: 7185)

NameError - uninitialized constant Nylas::API:
  app/controllers/email_connections_controller.rb:19:in `setup_nylas_client'
  app/controllers/email_connections_controller.rb:5:in `new'
  app/controllers/concerns/set_locale.rb:13:in `set_locale'

email_connections_controller.rb
def setup_nylas_client
  nylas_client = Nylas::API.new(
    app_id: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_ID'],
    app_secret: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    api_server: 'https://api.eu.nylas.com'
  )
end

app/controllers/nylas_controller.rb
require 'nylas'

class NylasController < ApplicationController
  def setup_nylas_client
    nylas_client = Nylas::API.new(
      app_id: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_ID'],
      app_secret: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_SECRET'],
      api_server: 'https://api.eu.nylas.com'
    )
    
  end
end

config/initializers/nylas.rb
require 'nylas'

$nylas_client = Nylas::API.new(
  app_id: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_ID'],
  app_secret: ENV['NYLAS_CLIENT_SECRET'],
  api_server: 'https://api.eu.nylas.com'
)

I ensured the nylas gem is included in the Gemfile and installed.
I added require 'nylas' at the top of the initializer and controller where Nylas::API is used.
Despite these attempts, the error persists.

Believe it should be Nylas::Client.new not Nylas::API.new
